# how to check class of anchor tag on the basis of its id in watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

**I have anchor tag html ,I want to check if anchor tag having class="disabled" on the basis of its id. this is my anchor tag**

```
<a onclick="setOutputType('COMP');" id="tab_Companies" disabled="disabled" NavigateUrl="#"     class="disabled">clickhere</a>
```

*I want to do some thing like that*

```
ie.link(:id, "tab_Companies").(:class,"disabled").exists? #this is wrong
```

**what should I do for it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
browser.a(:id => "tab_Companies").class_name
# => "disabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

**I got it, I do**

```
ie.div(:id => "tab_Companies", :class => 'disabled').exists?
```